# Input Delay at start of iOS game

Tags: ios, performance, debugging, opengl-es, delay

When I run my iOS game on a device, for a minute from the start approximately there is a delay in input: when I touch the screen somewhere, the game recognizes that touch only after 2 to 3 seconds; the accelerometer also shows the current orientation from 3 seconds ago!

I know it's not my coding, because after the first minute (approximately), the game starts behaving correctly, with input recognized at real time.

I suspect it also has something to do with my game running slow, but I can't find what's causing it. Is there something general that could be causing the delay, or can it be something specific to my code?

Comment: I have solved this; the problem was setting the Accelerometer/Gyroscope to update at 60 fps. I removed it from my app, and now it works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is so many reasons for this, but as a start try using Instruments to record the performance of the game, and u could postpone the actual start of the game a few seconds till everything gets properly loaded.
it is very likely that there is a loop somewhere that is doing quite more iterations than it is supposed to.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that it does draw everything at 60 fps at all times and from the start uninterruptedly, it's just the input that is delayed. There are no lags - it runs smoothly at 60 fps. It's like the input is delivered to the game only after some seconds.

Comment: would it be possible that the drawing of each frame is chained that there is no CPU time to process the touch, thus it gets delayed ? try to lower the FPS and see how it would go.

Comment: I've already made it run at 30 FPS, but it's still late. Sometimes it starts late and gets better after some time, and sometimes it starts fine but gets increasingly delayed... It seems really random.

Comment: did it improve in compare to 60 FPS? 
try to set the FPS to be dynamic according to how heavy the frames are getting. like a busy moment on the screen and a light one. is response related to that while u are playing ?

Comment: I don't think it's related. The game runs fine (my objects' actions and the drawing keep at 60 FPS at all times, easily). It's just that input is delayed some random amount, at seemingly random times. And it appears delay only happens when I test on a real device - Simulator seems to run fine every time.